# this and const in depth

Tags: c++, operators, overloading, operator-keyword

can someone go into detail about *this and const in operator overloading in regards to self assignment

ex:

```
Class& Class::operator=(const Class& other)
{
    a = other.a
    b = other.b

    return *this;
}
```

I am confused in what I am actually returning, am I returning a dereferenced pointer of myself to myself? Is this really how self assignment should work? I always feel there is a little bit more to it, I know this was explained in previous examples but I am more concerned on why it is getting "const" and returning "*this"

Also versus explicitly saying a = other.a, is there a difference if I made an actual copy of the const's values? Would this be more inefficient or it should be that way? - copy the const first then assign a to the copy's values.

If I returned "this" would I be returning a pointer to myself? I am pretty confused about this topic.

Comment: Did it compile, because if you have `cosnt Object& object` operator = makes no sense, all you say there is "I wont alter the RHS directly" via this call which helps the optimiser, the meaning of = is up to the programmer

Comment: I am talking about theory vs actual code. I want someone to sorta explain the differences to me and verify if what I am thinking is valid.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I have worked with C++, and hopefully I remember the details correctly.

For *am I returning a dereferenced pointer of myself to myself?*
Yes, and that is correct.  That is because the assignment function returns a reference (so you need to deference the this pointer so the function can return a reference to the object).

*Is this really how self assignment should work?*
Yes.

It is correct that the argument to the assignment operator (I tend think of it more as an assignment function) is const as you don't want to change what you are passing in (avoid side effects).

However, you should test to see if you are assigning items to yourself by checking the address of the object passed in against the this pointer. For reference, see [C++ : Implementing copy constructor and copy assignment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700991/c-implementing-copy-constructor-and-copy-assignment-operator).   For your example:

```
Class& Class::operator=(const Class& other)
{
  if ( this != &other ) 
  {
    a = other.a
    b = other.b
  }

  return *this;
}
```

If I recall correctly an example doing multiple assignments shows why the assignment operations works.  If you have x, y, z and you did the following, 
    x=y=z

Then y is assigned z, and they x is assign y, so returning reference (which is what assignment operator requires as input).

Hope that helps.